# Finding histograms properties in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a data set (called A) which contains positive integer numbers.

I want to find numbers in x and y axis of the histogram of A in two different vectors. I want a vector of unique values and a vector with the count for each values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a vector `x` of **unique values** and a vector `y` of their **occurrence counts**:

```
x = unique(A(:)).';
y = sum(bsxfun(@eq,A(:),x),1);
```

Or, alternatively,

```
x = unique(A(:)).';
y = histcounts(A, [x inf]);
```

Comment: When I use xx=[3,5,6,8,9,0,3,5,3,6,7,3,3,3,6]; [y, x] = hist(xx); x is not equal to integer numbers. I want x and y to be integer numbers from miimum to maximum of my data

Comment: @Oliver That's not what your question says at all (before the edit). Besides, `hist` does not necessarily produce a graph with integer _x_ values. The _x_-axis _ticks_ are integers, but the centers of the bars are at arbitrary horizontal positions

Comment: If `hist` doesn't produce integers, why do you want integers? And _how_ do you define which integers you want? Round to closest? Round to zero? ...?

Comment: Newer versions of matlab discourage using [`hist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html). Use [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) or [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) instead.

Comment: Also you can specify, what bin edges you wish in your histogram. Adding to this answer, you can try: `[y,x] = hist(A,1:10);` or `[y,x] = histcounts(A,1:10);`

Comment: @kedarps The problem with that approach, and the reason why I suggested `bsxfun` instead (see comments in the question post), is that `A = [10 10 20 30 30]; histcounts(A, unique(A))` would give `[2 3]` rather than `[2 1 2]`. You would need something like `A = [10 10 20 30 30]; histcounts(A, [unique(A) inf])` (or use the discouraged `histc(A, unique(A))`). I'll add that to the answer though

Comment: Is there a way to normalize y data?

Comment: Define "normalize"